# REGEX to extract subdomains

Tags: r, regex

I wanted to separate the subdomains of URL's using Regex in R,

For example:

```
 week.sddhdjs.net 
 sate.ghdutdjd.org 
 west.lakmeouh.com
 dhdj.ckisnsns.us?mdeddde
 werst.urhsbss.xyz?swasrr
```

Required Output should be like

```
sddhdjs.net
lakmeouh.com
urhsbss.xyz
kisnsns.us
```

Can you please get me your ides on it?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: foo %>% seperate(URL,into=c("a","b) ,sep = "(?<=[a-z])\\.(?=[a-z]+)"))

Comment: `gsub("^.*?\\.|\\?.*", "", x, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the `urltools` package.

```
library(urltools)

 x <- "http://www.someone.somethingelse.com.cy/images/phfdoc/fhdemiado.tam.fidfhfdde/" 

suffix_extract(domain(x))
#                              host   subdomain        domain suffix
#1 www.someone.somethingelse.com.cy www.someone somethingelse com.cy
```

**NOTE:** Obviously you will need to remove the leading `www` which can be done by a simple regex or any string-split method

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in base R with `sub`

```
sub(".*\\b(\\w+\\.\\w+).*", "\\1", URLs) 
[1] "sddhdjs.net"  "ghdutdjd.org" "lakmeouh.com" "ckisnsns.us"  "urhsbss.xyz"
```

Comment: Many thanks, it worked as expected. I'm just going to implement few more things on it. See you!

Comment: This (and I guess all answers) will fail for domains with such TLD as `.com.cy` or `.ac.uk`, etc...

Comment: @Sotos You are right. This will only work if the domain does not contain a `.`

Comment: @Sotos Yes You guys are Right. it's not working if a domain contains like abcd.xxxx.com.ir, abcd.xxxx.com.uy, abcd.xxxx.com.eu, etc etc.. Do you have any more thoughts to get an output  like xxxx.com.uy...?? .. I'm also investigating further  here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this with `stringr` and `substring` for removing the first char (the dot):

```
array <- c('week.sddhdjs.net',
           'sate.ghdutdjd.org',
           'west.lakmeouh.com',
           'dhdj.ckisnsns.us?mdeddde',
           'werst.urhsbss.xyz?swasrr')]

library(stringr)
array <- str_extract(array, '\\.\\S+') %>% substring(2)
```

The output:

```
[1] "sddhdjs.net"         "ghdutdjd.org"        "lakmeouh.com"        "ckisnsns.us?mdeddde" "urhsbss.xyz?swasrr"
```

Comment: Oh, now I saw you want to remove the end too, I'll try to fix later.

Answer (score 0):

The function below two packages: `dplyr` & `urltools`

```
Subdomain <- function(url)
{
 gsub("https://|http://|www.", "", url) %>% 
    urltools::domain() %>% urltools::suffix_extract() %>% 
      select(subdomain) %>% unlist(use.names = F)
}
```

Outputs

```
x <- c("https://link.abc.com/click", "google.com/flights", "yahoo.co.uk", "mail.yahoo.com")

Subdomain(x)
[1] "link" NA     NA     "mail"
```